# Multiple Controls in a Listbox item 

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I need to be able to have as many controls to fit in "One row of a list box" as possible. The goal is not to waste space on the form. The List Box will be the 70% height of the form (30% being a ribbon) and 100% width.

I use a custom ItemTempleSelector so the controls that will be in the list will be either a combination of:

Label + textbox, Label + combobox, Label + datetimepicker

Of course these appear one under another, but I need them to appear left to right.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is modify the `ListBox`'s `ItemsPanel` to contain a `WrapPanel`. This way your items will be displayed left to right and then wrap down to the next line (I think that's what you want). You also need to disable the horizontal scroll bar on the list box.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        ...your other stuff like the ItemTemplate
    </ListBox>
```

The other thing to think about is are you using a `ListBox` because you want them to be able to select each item?
If not, an `ItemsControl` would be a one for one replacement that's lighter weight and doesn't support selecting an item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but why don't you put all of your controls into a Wrappanel, and that is your root control in the datatemplate.

Comment: It is not the easiest situation to explain. The list will have an itemsource, which will be a List<t> of my custom custom object. this object has an enum will determines if the control in the listbox should be 1 of the orignally stated controls. The actual list bound to the list box is varying on check buttons in the ribbon, so it can change often.